# Parsing JSON data for weather app

Tags: android, json

I am trying to display weather data that I get from open weather map. The data seems to be sitting in the json variable however I can not parse that correctly.

```
<current>
<city id="4459467" name="Cary">
<coord lon="-78.78" lat="35.79"/>
<country>US</country>
<sun rise="2016-09-11T10:55:38" set="2016-09-11T23:26:18"/>
</city>
<temperature value="304.23" min="302.15" max="305.37" unit="kelvin"/>    
<humidity value="45" unit="%"/>
<pressure value="1018" unit="hPa"/>
<wind>
<speed value="2.6" name="Light breeze"/>
<gusts/><direction value="0" code="N" name="North"/>
</wind>
<clouds value="75" name="broken clouds"/>
<visibility/>
<precipitation mode="no"/>
<weather number="803" value="broken clouds" icon="04d"/>
<lastupdate value="2016-09-11T18:08:01"/></current>
```

This is the data from open weather with correct api key. I am trying to parse just the city, temperature, pressure and humidity.

Here is the weather fragment

```
public class Weather_fragment extends Fragment {

    TextView cityField;
    TextView detailsField;
    TextView currentTemperatureField;

    Handler handler;

    public Weather_fragment(){
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_fragment, container, false);

        cityField = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.city_field);
        detailsField = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.details_field);
        currentTemperatureField = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_temperature_field);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        updateWeatherData(new CityPreference(getActivity()).getCity());
    }

    private void updateWeatherData(final String city){
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                final JSONObject json = Fetch.getJSON(getActivity(), city);
                if(json == null){
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                getActivity().getString(R.string.place_not_found),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            renderWeather(json);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void renderWeather(JSONObject json){
        try {

           cityField.setText(json.getString("name").toUpperCase(Locale.US));

            JSONObject main = json.getJSONObject("main");
            detailsField.setText("Humidity: " + main.getString("humidity") + "%" +
                "\n" + "Pressure: " + main.getString("pressure") + " hPa");

            currentTemperatureField.setText(String.format("%.2f", main.getDouble("temp"))+ " ℃");

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("SimpleWeather", "error");
        }
    }


    public void changeCity(String city){
        updateWeatherData(city);
    }
}
```

This is the fetch java class

```
public class Fetch {

    private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API =
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";

    public static JSONObject getJSON(Context context, String city){
        try {

            String City = "Sydney, AU";
            URL url = new URL(String.format(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API, City));
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", context.getString(R.string.open_weather_maps_app_id));

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer Weatherdata = new StringBuffer();
            String storage = "";
            while((storage=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                Weatherdata.append(storage  + "\n");
            }

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(Weatherdata.toString());
            return data;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [ANDROID, Parse JSON data from a web server and display on ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36243380/2311047)

Comment: data is not json it is in xml

Comment: But your code is calling JSON object

Comment: I am calling for a json object but the html is written in xml. I actually had to take the code and store it into a string buffer than parse it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the HTML from the JSON response and then only you will be able to retrieve the JSONArray which you can then parse to get your data. Like below :

```
public String stripHtmlResponse (String html) {
    return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}
```

Source : [How to strip HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android)

Then retrive the data from JSONArray as follows

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
String noHTML = stripHtml(data);

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(noHTML);

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    // Do parsing of your JSONArray for required data
}
```

Comment: so after completing the fetch activity the JSON Object json that I am sending to renderweather needs to be striped of the html.There for I would put this code apart of renderweather is that correct?

Comment: You can put the stripHtmlResponse function anywhere in the class. And use the retrive JSONArray code  where ever you receive the response object.

Comment: I am a little lost on this part of the code.
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
String noHTML = stripHtml(data);
This shows up as undefined variables

I sent the JSONObject json to the striphtmlresponse it still exceptions out at the current moment.

Comment: Not sure this answers the question... The data shown isn't even JSON

Comment: you answered my question and I realized I wasted 3 hours trying to read something that was not even json.....

Answer (score 0):

The code example is not JSON but XML. However, if you want to parse a JSON String i suggest using GenSON. The repo for the library is https://github.com/EvgeniGenchev/GenSON-lib . Inside you can find example java code for parsing from OpenWeather API's.